# connect EADDRINUSE: cannot use node.js tcp client localPort after reconnecting within 30 seconds?

Tags: node.js, tcp

I have created a tcp server and a tcp client.
In my tcp client, I have specified the `localPort` because I want to use some specific ports in case of reconnection.

Below is my tcp server and client's code

**TCP SERVER**

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
  socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
  socket.pipe(socket);
  socket.on('error', function(err){
    console.log('on socket error', err);
  })
});

server.on('error', function(err){
  console.log('on error',err);
})

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

**TCP CLIENT**

```
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect({port: 1337, host: '127.0.0.1', localPort: 10002}, function() {
  console.log('Connected');
  client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client.');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('Received: ' + data);
  client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});

client.on('close', function() {
  console.log('Connection closed');
});
client.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('error in connection',err);
});
```

I have this server and client in two separate files.
If I run the server, and then run the client for the first time, everything works fine.
But as soon as I re-run(reconnect) the client, it gives me an error

```
{ Error: connect EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:1337 - Local (0.0.0.0:10002)
    at internalConnect (net.js:964:16)
    at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (internal/async_hooks.js:281:19)
    at net.js:1062:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:696:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 1337 }
```

It works fine if I retry after around 30 seconds.

Does net in nodejs have a TIMEOUT of not using the same localPort for 30 seconds?
If it is so, can we reduce it or manage it somehow?